# It is a way to remove fish eye from a gopro or yi 4k action camera without loosing quality or without replace the lenses?

Tags: fisheye, gopro, hd-video

It is a way to remove fisheye from a gopro or yi 4k action camera without loosing quality or without replace the lenses ? (regarding the video)

Comment: Video is off-topic here, it's a question for video.stackexchange.com. Anyway, I suggest you make some research on the subject, I am pretty sure that you will find what you are looking for, using your favorite search engine with "video processing red eye".

Comment: @Olivier OP wasn't asking about **red** eye, he was asking to _defish_ the wide angle. However, agreed on off-topic.

Comment: Yep, I don't know why but probably at the time of writing my comment "red eye" sounded better than "fisheye" :)

Comment: I'm not sure about removing in post, but you can adjust the settings on a GoPro before you shoot, narrowing the field from wide to normal

Comment: The answer is the same whether you are taking stills or video.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can, in theory, add supplemental lenses to change the field of view — however this almost inevitably affects quality. Supplementary lenses tend to be low quality.

You can crop the image/video in post-processing — but this reduces quality (at least in terms of number of image pixels)

Replacing the lens is certainly the best way to get a narrower field of view without reducing quality.